# Variable referenced before assignment - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting the error...

```
a = a + b
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand why the error occurs if I have assigned the two variables a and b at the start.

```
from tkinter import *

a = 10
b = 12
def stopProg(e):
    root.destroy()

def addNumbers(e):
    a = a + b
    label1.configure(text= str(a))

root=Tk()
button1=Button(root,text="Exit")
button1.pack()
button1.bind('<Button-1>',stopProg)
button2=Button(root,text="Add numbers")
button2.pack()
button2.bind('<Button-1>',addNumbers)
label1=Label(root,text="Amount")
label1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you modify a global variable inside a function, you need to first declare that variable as being global.

So, you need to do this for the global variable `a` since you modify it inside `addNumbers`:

```
def addNumbers(e):
    global a
    # This is the same as: a = a + b
    a += b
    # You don't need str here
    label1.configure(text=a)
```

Here is a reference on the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html) keyword.

---

Also, I would like to point out that your code can be improved if you use the `command` option of `Button`:

```
from tkinter import *

a = 10
b = 12
def stopProg():
    root.destroy()

def addNumbers():
    global a
    a += b
    label1.configure(text=a)

root=Tk()
button1=Button(root, text="Exit", command=stopProg)
button1.pack()
button2=Button(root, text="Add numbers", command=addNumbers)
button2.pack()
label1=Label(root, text="Amount")
label1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There is never a good reason to use binding in place of the `command` option.

Comment: Out of all the lectures I have went to, I have never been shown this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask what is 'e' for in here - 'def stopProg(e)' ? Thanks.

Comment: @Amber.G - It is to hold the event object that will be passed to the function by `.bind()`. You'll notice though that I removed it from the updated code since we are now using `command`, which does not send an event object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer :

This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope.

Please read this : http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying a global variable. By default, you can read values from global variables, without declaring them as `global`, but to modify them you need to declare them as `global` like this

```
global a
a = a + b
```